# Console outputting too many results

Tags: c#, console

I want to receive only 1 value for as_x, written in the console, but I always get 2 values, with one completely wrong like "infinity", "not defined" or an strange value.
The "pressure" contains the 3 shown "enum" values.
What I want to do is to calculate the as_x at the end. Therefore, depending on lookupValuemux, I get a value for omega. And depending on the value of omega there are 3 different ways to calculate the as_x. 
I am a real beginner in programming, so any help would be great.

```
double omega;
double as_x;
pressure design;
double M_Eds_lim = 0.296 * Math.Pow(d, 2) * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c);
double delta_M_Ed = mx - M_Eds_lim;

omega = 0;
design = 0;
as_x = 0;

double mux = mx / (Math.Pow(d, 2) * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c));
double lookupValuemux = Math.Round(mux, 2);


if (lookupValuemux < 0.01) {
    design = pressure.min;
} else if ((lookupValuemux >= 0.01) && (lookupValuemux < 0.30))  {
    design = pressure.tension;
    omega = design_force.omegaTable[lookupValuemux][0];
} else if (lookupValuemux >= 0.30); {
    design = pressure.steel;
    omega = 0.3643;
};

if (design == pressure.min) {
    as_x = As_min;
    Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
} else if (design == pressure.tension) {
    as_x = omega * d * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s);
    Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
} else if (design == pressure.steel); { 
    as_x = omega * d * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s) + delta_M_Ed / (d - d_2) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s);
    Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
}
```

Comment: Remove the extra semicolon after the second `else if`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Anyone got another idea? I'm sorry, but I still didn't get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In the unedited original post, this line had a spurious semicolon at the end:

```
else if (design == pressure.steel);
```

This has been edited away by someone other than the OP (not by dasblinkenlight either), so the semicolon is no longer there in the question.

Since this is what is causing `as_x` to be printed twice, it is unhelpful that it was edited out.

Note that there is another superfluous semicolon remaining in this line:

```
} else if (lookupValuemux >= 0.30); {
```

which should also be removed.

This is how the second half of the original post appeared:

```
if (design == pressure.min)
{
as_x = As_min;
Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
}
else if (design == pressure.tension)
{
as_x = omega * d * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s);
Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
}

else if (design == pressure.steel); // <---- LOOKIE HERE

{ 
as_x = omega * d * (fck * design_force.alpha_cc / design_force.gamma_c) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s) + delta_M_Ed / (d - d_2) / (f_yk / design_force.gamma_s);
Console.WriteLine("asx ID " + ID + "asx  =  " + as_x);
}
```

Comment: I added the semicolon back into the question, the semicolon should not have been removed since it is part of the problem here.

Comment: I tried to play around with the semicolons, but this didn't solve my problem yet. I think my combination of enum query and the if /else if is kinda wrong.